# C math on user input

Tags: c, user-input

I'm new to c and I'm trying to preform maths on a user input, specifically the year of a date.
When I try to divide , or do any maths on the variable 'y' and store it in 'fpy' it will always print the value '6422032' or close to it. Any help would be great, I've been trying for hours now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int d,m,f,y,spY;
    
    //char y[3]; 
    printf("Day from date calculator \n");
    printf("Please enter the date in DD/MM/YYYY formate. For example , 1/7/1440 \n");
    printf(">");
    scanf("%d/%d/%i",&d,&m,&y);
    int fpy = y/10;
    printf("%d",&fpy);
    






    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `&` when you call `printf`.

Comment: Side note: It is generally a good idea to always check the return value of `scanf` to check whether the function was successful, before attempting to use its result.

Comment: In the last printf-call you print the address of `fpy` instead of `fpy` itself

Comment: Side note: You only need to `#include <math.h>` when the code is using the floating point functions (eg: sin(), cos(), tan()) in that library. For this integer manipulation (and adding/subtracting.. floating point numbers) there's no need for `math.h`. (To `#include` unnecessary bits causes the reader to wonder, "Why is that there?") Also, `stdlib.h` is not contributing to this program as it stands.

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you a warning like `format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’` for the line `printf("%d", &fpy);`, you should probably figure out a way to increase its warning level, or get a better compiler.

Comment: What the heck is "maths"?!?

Answer (score 1):

this

```
printf("%d",&fpy);
```

should be

```
printf("%d",fpy);
```